# Changing custom control style dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Changing custom control style dynamically

I am trying to use react to put red border around each custom field that is empty. array `this.state.Fields` contains all the controls to be checked.
I want to check every required control and if its value not set, change its `style` property. Since properties cannot be changed, I tried to use `state` but the problem is I'd need to have a separate vriable for each control:

```
<Control ref="controlLabel" name="controlLabel" type="1" onComponentMounted={this.register} label="Control Label:" required="1" value={this.state.controlLabel} localChange={this.handleControlLabelChange} inputStyle={{border: this.state.errControlLabelStyle}} />
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do that? Here is my code:

```
this.state.Fields.forEach((field) => {
    if(field.props.required === "1"){
        var validField = (field.props.value != '' && field.props.value != undefined);
        if(!validField){
                //set the field style dynamically              
        }
}
validForm=validForm && validField;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add validation logic inside Control itself.

```js
var Control = React.createClass({
 isValid: function() {
   if (!this.props.required) {
     return true;
    }
   return this.props.value !== '' && this.props.value !== undefined;
  },

  render: function() {
   let value = this.props.value;
    return <div className={this.isValid() ? 'item valid' : 'item invalid'}>{value}</div>;
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <div className="container">
       {[
        {
          required: true,
          value: ''
        },
        {
          required: true,
          value: 'abc'
        },
        {
          required: false,
          value: ''
        }
        ].map((v, i) => <Control key={i} required={v.required} value={v.value} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.valid {
   border-color:  green;
}

.invalid {
  border-color: red;
 }
 
 .item {
   width:  200px;
   height: 50px;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   margin: 1px;
   display: flex;
 }
 
 .container {
   display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: that sounds good, what I am trying to do is activate the code on button-click, the way you suggested would render the control as invalid to begin with, wouldn't it?

Comment: right now yes. In order to extend it you could add property isValid on your data object and change it on button click

Comment: but wouldn't it lead me to the same thing I started with? I will add a property to custom control and in order to change it from the parent I will need to use state and will have to set separate state for each child control on the page

Comment: Not necessarily, I am suggesting to add isValid property to your data object. It doesn't need to be in the parent. In that model you would not use state anywhere except top container with your data object. Another option is to pass field showValidation (via either props or context) that would trigger control to change style.

Comment: what are you referring to as the data object?

Comment: It is set of fields that you are trying to validate in this case: {
          required: true,
          value: 'abc'
        }

Comment: could you give me an example of the above?